# ReflectionException in Route.php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm getting this error on my laravel 5 project in my login urls:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Marketplaces\Marketplace1\Auth\AuthController does not exist
```

This is my routes.marketplace1.php file:

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/marketplace/mkt1', '\App\Http\Controllers\Marketplaces\Mkt1Controller@index');
});
```

And this is my routes.php file:

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

The folder structure is this:

```
app
 Http
  Routes
   routes.mkt1.php
   routes.php
```

And the folder for the controllers:

```
app
 Http
  Controllers
   Auth
   Marketplaces
    Mkt1
     Mkt1Controller.php
   HomeController.php
```

And this is my RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
    protected $mkt1Namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Marketplaces\Cnova';
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);
    }

    public function map(Router $router)
    {

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/Routes/routes.php');
        });

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->mkt1Namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/Routes/routes.mkt1.php');
        });    
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: where is your authController

Comment: AuthController.php is in app->Http->Controllers->Auth @KrisRoofe